# Multiple queries of related models in remote method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, loopbackjs

I'm new to nodejs and Loopback/Express . I'm trying to write a trivial application involving an API call that has multiple db requests of related models, but I coudln't find any relevant documentation or examples that show this.

Imagine 3 models: Author, Post and Rating.  Each Post hasOne Author and hasMany Ratings.  A Ratings has an integer value called 'stars'.

I'm creating a custom API remoteMethod for Posts called 'details' which should return all of the following:

- Post details
- Author details (stored in the related Author model)
- Number of related Ratings having stars==1
- Number of related Ratings having stars==2
- Number of related Ratings having stars==3

What's the best way to implement this having the lowest and more parallel number of db queries?  I've tried the following code using Promises, but essentially it's an inefficient synchronous code that makes multiple unnecessary queries to the database and it quickly becomes very messy.

```
Post.details = function(id, cb) {

var LoopBackContext = require('loopback-context');
var app = require('../../server/server'); 
var Author = app.models.Author;
var Rating = app.models.Rating;

var response = {post: null,
                author: null,
                ratings_0: null,
                ratings_1: null,
                ratings_2: null
  };

Post.findById(id, {include: 'author', where: {deleted: false}})
    .then(function(p) {
        response.post = p;
        return Author.findById(p.authorId);
    })
    .then(function(r) {
        response.author = r;
        return Rating.find({where: {postId: id, stars: 0}});
    })
    .then(function(r) {
        response.votes_0 = r.length;
        return Rating.find({where: {postId: id, stars: 1}});
    })
    .then(function(r) {
        response.votes_1 = r.length;
        return Rating.find({where: {postId: id, stars: 2}});
    })
    .then(function(r) {
        response.votes_2 = r.length;
        cb(null, response);
    });

  };
```

Which is rather too much for such a trivial thing. I also tried using 'include' in the queries, but it also becomes difficult to use and it doesn't support level-2 filters in Loopback.

What's the best way to implement this?

Comment: You could do all this requests in parallel with Promise.all

Answer (score 2):

Well with a little refactoring and changes, it'll be very short and straightforward:

```
Post.details = function(id) {
  var app = require('../../server/server'); 
  var Rating = app.models.Rating;

  return Promise.all([
    Post.findById(id, {include: 'author', where: {deleted: false}}),
    Rating.count({ where: {postId: id, stars: 0}}),
    Rating.count({ where: {postId: id, stars: 1}}),
    Rating.count({ where: {postId: id, stars: 2}}),
  ]).then([post, ratings_0, ratings_1, ratings_2]) => {
    return {
      post,
      author: post.author,
      ratings_0,
      ratings_1,
      ratings_2,
    };
  });
};
```

There's a couple of things going on here:

- You don't need `Author.findById`, assuming `include: 'author'` covers it.
- As for the ratings count, you just used the `Rating.count` method. It'll be faster since there's less bandwidth used and database can serve data faster if there's an index for it since it'll be served directly from the index.
- I've used ES6 destructing, object literal shorthand and arrow function.
- If you return a promise in a loopback remote method, it'll use the method return value for the request response instead of the callback.
- Promise.all will run the queries in parallel and finishes when all given queries are completed.